# fields use to implement hash and comparison functions in unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, comparison-operators

Is it necessary for the comparison and the hash function of a custom type in an `std::unordered_map` to use the *same* set of fields? (i.e) given:

```
struct Foo { int i; float f; };
```

If I generate hashes only using `i` but use both `i` and `f` to implement equality, will I run afoul of anything? In my understanding, the comparison function is used to determine the relative ordering of objects *within* a bucket. So I don't think there should be a problem but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @john Thanks! I would like to mark yours as the correct answer if you are inclined to hoist it out of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine, all that is required is that x == y implies hash(x) == hash(y) which your scheme does.